# Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm making a form to update my MySQL database, but for some reason I get the following error in my browser:

```
C:\wamp\www\Helpdeskapplicatie\update_hardware.php on line 49
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong??

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="menu">
            <div id="menu_wrapper">
                <ul>
                    <li>Configuratiebeheer<img src="afb/pijltje.png" width="10"/></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="configuratiebeheer_hardware.php">Lijst hardware</a></li>
                            <li><a href="hardware_toevoegen.php">Hardware toevoegen</a></li>
                            <li><a href="hardware_verwijderen.php">Hardware verwijderen</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>      
<?php
            $connect=mysql_connect("localhost", "root","");
            mysql_select_db("helpdesk_middenpolder", $connect);
            $id=$_GET['id'];
            $q="SELECT * FROM hardware WHERE hardwareID=$id";


            $r=mysql_query($q);

            echo    "<table border='1'>";
            echo    "<th>merknaam</th><th>producttype</th><th>hardwaretype</th>";
            while   ($x=mysql_fetch_array($r)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo "<input type='text' value='".$x['merknaam']."'>";
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo "<input type='text' value='".$x['producttype']."'>";
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo "<input type='text' value='".$x['hardwaretype']."'>";
                echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";

        mysql_close($connect);
?>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['updatehardware'])){ 
        $query = "UPDATE hardware SET merknaam='".$x['merknaam']."', producttype='".$x['producttype']."', hardwaretype='".$x['hardwaretype']."' WHERE hardwareID='".$id['id']."'";
        mysql_query($query);
    }
?>


    <form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="updatehardware" value="Hardware updaten">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `$id` instead of `$id['id']` in that line

Comment: You're doing no input validation on data you're using to build an SQL query.  This can easily end in disaster as I could put any value I want in there, including SQL commands. http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your update query need to change like this,

```
hardwareID='".$id."'
```

instead of

```
hardwareID='".$id['id']."'
```

Comment: Can't I have to wait for like 5 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$id['id']` instead of `$_GET['id']`. However never trust passed with GET/POST data. Use instead:

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
```